# How to include ESP8266 mac as arg in GET request?

Tags: c++, string, arduino, esp8266

I am trying to build a request string that includes the ESP8266 WiFi.macAddress as an argument.  How can I put the MAC value in the middle of a URL get as shown below?

http://example.com/somepage.html?user=bob&mac=12:34:56:78:90:11&tries=7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WiFi.macAddress()` returns a `String`, so you can use the `+` operator to add the
value returned in your url

```
String url = "http://example.com/somepage.html?user=bob&" + WiFi.macAddress() + "&tries=7";
```

Comment: That's odd.  The doc says it returns a byte array.  https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFiMACAddress

Also what is "String" vs. "string"?  What's the difference?  I can't find an explanation.  Is it something other than std::string?

Comment: I checked it up in the source code for the `ESP8266WiFiSTA.h` before posting the answer, see if it works. And `String` is declared in the `<Arduino.h>` header file, it is similar to `std::string`; and easy for beginners to understand. Use this link to learn more about `String` https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/

Comment: Thanks.  I tried it.  It works.  I am just trying to understand why it works with "String" but doesn't work with "string", and to learn the differences. How do you know when to use which one, and how do you handle a byte array when working with pure c++, not Arduino...

Comment: I'd up-vote your answer, but I can't because people have down-voted an honest question.

Comment: Whenever you have such a question, you can just try to find it in the source code and see what data type a function takes, in Arduino functions like `Serial.print()` or esp8266 functions like `client.print()`, `server.send` accepts a `String`

Comment: And for using `std::string` vs `char *` or `char array` in pure c++, if you just want to store a string of text and nothing else, you can use a `char*`, but if you are looking for something more, the `std::string` class provides useful methods such as `length` and `find` which makes string manipulation a lot easier and faster.

Comment: By the way, I would have really appreciated an up-vote.

Comment: I just tried to up-vote it again, but StackOverflow won't allow me to.  Someone else please up-vote this answer.  He deserves it.